# Making a program that analyzes grammatical rules

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, indexing, range

I am making a program that prints out how many times the rule: **I before E, except after C** is broken, and how many times that rule has helped after reading multiple lines from the user until a blank line is entered (or whatever you want as long as the loop is not infinite).

This is how I want it to function:

```
Enter phrase: I before e except when conducting an efficient
Enter phrase: heist on eight foreign neighbours. I believe
Enter phrase: my friend has left the receipt for the
Enter phrase: diet books hidden in the ceiling.
Enter phrase: 
Number of times the rule helped: 5
Number of times the rule was broken: 5
```

And my code so far is:

```
worked = 0
incorrect = 0
line1 = ("Line: ")
while line != "":
  line = input("Line: ")
  line2 = line1.split()
  if "cie" in line2[a]:
    incorrect = incorrect + 1
  if "ie" in line2[a] and "cie" not in line2[a]:
    worked = worked + 1
  if "cei" in line2[a]:
    worked = worked + 1
  if "ei" in line2[a] and "cei" not in line2[a]:
    incorrect = incorrect + 1
  a = a + 1
print("Number of times the rule was correct:",worked,)
print("Number of times the rule was incorrect:",incorrect,)
```

HOWEVER, I get an index out of range error. I asked a few friends around and they can't seem to know why it is occurring as well. If someone can post a fix to it, thanks. If there is any way I can improve my post please let me know as well.

*EDIT* A was meant to be 0

Comment: Where do you originally define the variable `a`?

Comment: A was meant to be 0 for incrementing, not sure what I was trying to do come to think of it.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `in` and `not in` is not enough to produce correct results unless you limit input to only one use of "ie" or, if not only one use, only one usage (type of use).  There seems to be an attempt to analyze words in isolation, but the above is valid for words too.

The program needs to either use a RegEx (with a look-behind) or scan the text properly.

To answer your question, the "index out of range error" occurs because `line2` is a split of `line1`, which is constant `"Line: "`.  This means that `line2` is always equal to `["Line:"]`.  On the second iteration of the `while`, `a` takes the value 1, which is an invalid index for `line2`.

If you add `if a >= 1: break` before any use in the loop of `line2[a]`, this exception will not occur any more.  Now, for the reasons I expressed above, I don't think the program is going to accomplish its stated objectives anyways.